# Get all descendants of an entry

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, recursion, traversal

I have a huge referral system (Over 500k entries) that works like this

```
 [{id: 1, name: "John", ref: 0},
  {id: 2, name: "Jack", ref: 1},
  {id: 3, name: "Bill", ref: 1},
  {id: 5, name: "Jason", ref: 2},
  {id: 6, name: "James", ref: 3},
  {id: 7, name: "Tom", ref: 0}]
```

Whenever a user joins with other user's referral code, referrer gets some credits and It applies to all levels so in this example `John` gets credit for this IDs `[2, 3, 5, 6]`

I use this method to count and organize all entries based on their referral ID

```
   const countRefs = (list) => {
      return list.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        if(!acc[cur.ref]) acc[cur.ref] = [];
        acc[cur.ref].push(cur.id);
        return acc;
      },{});
    }
```

And then use this recursive function to get all referred users by an ID.

```
let depth = 0;
// Keep record of checked IDs
const checked = {};

const getTree = (list, ref) => {
// Check if referrer is already checked to avoid cycles
if(checked[ref]) return [];
  const ids = [];
  const items = list[ref] || [];
  checked[ref] = true;
  if (items.length && depth < 35000) {
    depth += 1;
    for (let ref of items) {
      if(!list[ref]) continue;
      const deep = getTree(list, ref, depth);
      ids.push(...deep);
    }
  }


  checked = {};
  depth = 0;
  return [...ids, ...items];
}
```

Now I have two questions:

1. Is there a better way of doing this? Like creating all relations within the first loop?
2. With some entries I get `Maximum Call Stack Error`. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: There's a maximum number of the recursive function calls. The exact number depends on the engine, but in any engine it's less than 35000. If you can't reduce data, you need to implement the logic with nested loops (i.e. keep up your own stack).

Comment: First, you should consider using nested loops. So many recursive calls for the respective data gives you an error that explains this website's name.

Comment: I tried to increase stack limit by passing `--stack-size` to the node but It keeps failing. I think there is a hole in my code because one user gets more than 130k IDs and it keeps growing until stack reaches maximum size.

Comment: I have no idea how to convert this recursive function to a nested loop since you can't determine number of levels

Comment: It looks like your input data structure has cycles. Where a person is a (remote) descendent of their own.

Comment: "*I have two questions"*: you should only ask one question. For the second question you should provide the minimal input for which that problem occurs.

Comment: Yes I though that there might be a cycle in my entries so I've added a variable to keep record of checked IDs but still I get the same error

Comment: Then implement the same algorithm, but using an explicit stack instead of recursion.

Comment: You know how deep it gets? Right now stack gets as deep as 35000 recursive calls! I have no idea how to do it with explicit stack

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of depth-first you could implement a breadth-first algorithm. In JavaScript a `Set` will be a nice data structure to work with, as entries of a set are always iterated in insertion-order, and a `for..of` loop over a set will keep looping as long as new entries are added to the set being looped over, giving it the behaviour of a queue.

A set will also act as `checked`: if an entry is already in the set, adding it again will not have any effect on the set, and so the entry will not be visited a second time.

No change is needed to `countRefs`, but I would give it a different name, as it doesn't return a count, but a tree.

And the second function doesn't return a tree, but a list of descendants. So I would also rename that one:

```js
// No change to this function
const makeTree = (list) => {
  return list.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    if (!acc[cur.ref]) acc[cur.ref] = [];
    acc[cur.ref].push(cur.id);
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

// Use breadth-first
const getDescendants = (list, ref) => {
  const children = new Set(list[ref] ?? []);
  for (const child of children) {
    for (const grandchild of list[child] ?? []) children.add(grandchild);
  }
  return [...children];
}

const list = [{id: 1, name: "John", ref: 0},
  {id: 2, name: "Jack", ref: 1},
  {id: 3, name: "Bill", ref: 1},
  {id: 5, name: "Jason", ref: 2},
  {id: 6, name: "James", ref: 3},
  {id: 7, name: "Tom", ref: 0}]

const tree = makeTree(list);
const descendants = getDescendants(tree, 1);
console.log(descendants);
```

Comment: Awesome mate! It worked and I'm not getting any stack errors right now. Thanks!

Comment: There's something that always bothers me about using a `for`-loop on a changing dataset.  But it's definitely easier to look at than my usual technique of keeping a queue of items to process and a separate list of results.

Comment: Ok, another technique for that isn't bad.  I like it better than this `for`-loop: `const getDescendants = (list, ref) => [... (list [ref] ?? []), ... (list [ref] ?? []) .flatMap (c => getDescendants (list, c))]`.  Or perhaps `const getDescendants = (list, ref, children = list [ref] ?? []) => [... children, ... children .flatMap (c => getDescendants (list, c))]` depending upon your feelings about default parameters.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a good opportunity to use a data structure to write a scalable solution.

- Build a tree data structure from the reference data

  - Create a node for each unique id
  - For each entry in the data, add a child node `id` to the node `ref`

  Note that by definition tree should not have cycles, i.e. an entry should not have its own id as `ref`
- Once the tree is in place, the problem boils down to finding the total number of nodes in each of the subtrees of the tree, which is a well studied problem. The time complexity required to solve this is `O(n)`, where n is the total number of nodes.

  In this case, the credit for a particular id will be:

  `Number of nodes in the subtree where that id is the root node - 1` (excluding itself).

  Implement the DFS iteratively instead of using recursive calls to avoid stack overflow (no pun intended)

Comment: Yes I thought about the same implantation too but I think It requires more resources to create a node for each unique `id` since I have more than 500k entries with unique

Comment: The implementation should indeed depend on your requirements. Creating a tree shouldn't be necessary if you're only concerned with finding credits for a single id or just a handful of ids. It will however be useful if you're finding credits for a lot of different ids. Also note that 500k isn't a big number in terms of memory requirement. Even if all the nodes are of size 100 bytes (which should be an overestimate as each node can only have one parent), 1 million nodes will take up 100 megabytes of space.